# Is there any closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

> Is there any closed form for this summation?
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}$$ where $n$ is finite and $x$ a real parameter

Comment: Nope, but it can be written using common special functions: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFunction.html

Comment: I think the [Incomplete Gamma Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html), $Γ(n,x)$, is closely (if not entirely) related to this. There's no known closed form for this.